# RMUniversalAlertで実装したアラートがiOS7でクラッシュする

Tags: ios, objective-c

RMUniversalAlertを使用して、iOS7とiOS8でアラートの出し分けを実装しているのですが、
iOS7でアラートを表示するとアプリがクラッシュするという問題が発生しています。

[RMUniversalAlertのサンプルソース](https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/RMUniversalAlert/tree/master/Tests)をプロジェクト内に入れて、動かしてみても同様にクラッシュしてしまうので、プログラムの書き方ではなく、プロジェクトの設定などが原因ではないかと考えていますが、原因を特定することができません。

事象が発生する原因と考えられる条件、または原因を特定する方法について教えていただきたいです。

### 問題が発生する端末とOSのバージョン

- iPhone5C / iOS 7.1.2
- iOS Simulator / iOS 7.1

### 事象が発生した際のトレース

```
#21582  0x0026034e in -[UIAlertView(Blocks) willPresentAlertView:] at /Users/yujiroarai/.ghq/yujiroarai/ios/APP/Pods/UIAlertView+Blocks/UIAlertView+Blocks.m:179
#21583  0x00229280 in -[A2DynamicUIAlertViewDelegate willPresentAlertView:] at /Users/yujiroarai/.ghq/yujiroarai/ios/APP/Pods/BlocksKit/BlocksKit/UIKit/UIAlertView+BlocksKit.m:50
#21584  0x0026034e in -[UIAlertView(Blocks) willPresentAlertView:] at /Users/yujiroarai/.ghq/yujiroarai/ios/APP/Pods/UIAlertView+Blocks/UIAlertView+Blocks.m:179
#21585  0x00229280 in -[A2DynamicUIAlertViewDelegate willPresentAlertView:] at /Users/yujiroarai/.ghq/yujiroarai/ios/APP/Pods/BlocksKit/BlocksKit/UIKit/UIAlertView+BlocksKit.m:50
#21586  0x0026034e in -[UIAlertView(Blocks) willPresentAlertView:] at /Users/yujiroarai/.ghq/yujiroarai/ios/APP/Pods/UIAlertView+Blocks/UIAlertView+Blocks.m:179
#21587  0x00229280 in -[A2DynamicUIAlertViewDelegate willPresentAlertView:] at /Users/yujiroarai/.ghq/yujiroarai/ios/APP/Pods/BlocksKit/BlocksKit/UIKit/UIAlertView+BlocksKit.m:50
#21588  0x3029dc5e in -[UIAlertView willPresentModalItem:] ()
#21589  0x30013c24 in -[_UIModalItemsCoordinator _presentItem:replacingItem:inViewController:animated:] ()
#21590  0x30013628 in -[UIViewController(UIModalItemPresentationSupport) presentModalItem:replacing:animated:dontPresentAndAddToStack:] ()
#21591  0x300135ac in -[UIViewController(UIModalItemPresentationSupport) presentModalItem:animated:] ()
#21592  0x3029e720 in -[UIAlertView popupAlertAnimated:animationType:atOffset:] ()
#21593  0x3029e946 in -[UIAlertView popupAlertAnimated:animationType:] ()
#21594  0x0025fbd0 in +[UIAlertView(Blocks) showWithTitle:message:style:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:tapBlock:] at /Users/yujiroarai/.ghq/yujiroarai/ios/APP/Pods/UIAlertView+Blocks/UIAlertView+Blocks.m:72
#21595  0x0025fcf2 in +[UIAlertView(Blocks) showWithTitle:message:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:tapBlock:] at /Users/yujiroarai/.ghq/yujiroarai/ios/APP/Pods/UIAlertView+Blocks/UIAlertView+Blocks.m:88
#21596  0x00232ca2 in +[RMUniversalAlert showAlertInViewController:withTitle:message:cancelButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:tapBlock:] at /Users/yujiroarai/.ghq/yujiroarai/ios/APP/Pods/RMUniversalAlert/RMUniversalAlert.m:71
#21597  0x0012dba8 in -[ViewController singleOther:] at /Users/yujiroarai/.ghq/yujiroarai/ios/APP/APP/Classes/Controller/ViewController.m:121
#21598  0x2fe396a6 in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#21599  0x2fe39642 in -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] ()
#21600  0x2fe39612 in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] ()
#21601  0x2fe24d5a in -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()
#21602  0x2fe3905a in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#21603  0x2fe38d2c in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#21604  0x2fe33c86 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#21605  0x2fe08e54 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#21606  0x2fe07520 in _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue ()
#21607  0x2d59dfae in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#21608  0x2d59d476 in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#21609  0x2d59bc66 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#21610  0x2d506728 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#21611  0x2d50650a in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#21612  0x324756d2 in GSEventRunModal ()
#21613  0x2fe67870 in UIApplicationMain ()
#21614  0x0011c97c in main at /Users/yujiroarai/.ghq/yujiroarai/ios/APP/APP/main.m:14
```

Comment: Blocksを使うのをやめて、iOS7のときはviewControllerにdelegateする方法で暫定対応することにしました！
暫定対応したソース https://github.com/yujiroarai/RMUniversalAlert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocksを使うのをやめて、iOS7のときはviewControllerにdelegateする方法で暫定対応することに‌​しました！